# Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem' to type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFile

Tags: 2010, document-library, splistitem, spfile

In code below, at mentioned line I am getting this error: How I fix this?

```
SPList docLib = WSweb.GetList(WSweb.ServerRelativeUrl + "/Documents");
//SPList docLib = WSweb.Lists.TryGetList("Documents");
if (docLib != null) {

    SPDocumentLibrary docs = (SPDocumentLibrary) docLib;
    SPQuery checkedOutDocs = new SPQuery();
    checkedOutDocs.Query = @"<Where><IsNotNull>
         <FieldRef Name='CheckoutUser' />
          </IsNotNull></Where>
           <QueryOptions>
            <ViewAttributes Scope='RecursiveAll' />
            </QueryOptions>";
    checkedOutDocs.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='ID' />";
    checkedOutDocs.ViewFieldsOnly = true;
    SPListItemCollection items = docs.GetItems(checkedOutDocs);

    foreach(SPFile file in items) // At this line i am getting error
    {
        if (docmanager.getFileExtension(file.Item) == ".pdf") {
            if (file.LockId != null) {
                file.CheckIn("Checked in programatically!");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SPListItemCollection` is a collection of `SPListItem`. Get `File` object from `SPListItem`. Example:

```
foreach (SPListItem item in items)
{
   SPFile file = item.File;
}
```

Comment: at this line: SPFile file = item.File; item.File returns null. why is that I have debug and i can see file ab.pdf when i hover over cursor on item

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using SPFile object use the SPListItem in foreach loop. And within the loop we can use the File property of SPListItem to get the SPFile object.

Try the below code...

```
foreach (SPListItem item in items){
SPFile file = item.File;
    if(docmanager.getFileExtension(item) == ".pdf"){
                if (file.LockId != null){
            file.CheckIn("Checked in programatically!");
                 }
        }
}
```